# How can I expand a pandas timestamp by year?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a single date:

```
birth_day = pd.to_datetime('1984-09-03')
```

and I am trying to create a series of dates, repeating yearly. This is what I tried:

```
birth_days = birth_day + pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(10), 'Y')
```

The output is not exactly what I expect. The generated dates have different hour information:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1984-09-03 00:00:00', '1985-09-03 05:49:12',
               '1986-09-03 11:38:24', '1987-09-03 17:27:36',
               '1988-09-02 23:16:48', '1989-09-03 05:06:00',
               '1990-09-03 10:55:12', '1991-09-03 16:44:24',
               '1992-09-02 22:33:36', '1993-09-03 04:22:48'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

How can I create this list where all hours are `00:00:00`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `DateOffset`

```
[birth_day-pd.DateOffset(years=x) for x in np.arange(10)]
Out[87]: 
[Timestamp('1984-09-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1983-09-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1982-09-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1981-09-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1980-09-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1979-09-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1978-09-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1977-09-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1976-09-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1975-09-03 00:00:00')]
```

Comment: @KorayTugay I think the function have problem you can pull out `pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(10), 'Y')` to see